# Locating variable based on confidence interval for exponential distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem, confidence-interval

$X$ is a random variable and its PDF is:

$$
  f(x;θ) = \begin{cases} θe^{-θx}, & x > 0 \\\ 0, & x \le 0 \end{cases}
$$

Now, I would like to find the confidence interval regarding parameter $θ$

$$
  S(x) = \{θ|0 < θ \le \dfrac{c}{x}\}
$$

$c$ is a constant that satisfies $P(θ \in S(X)) = 1 - α$ (α is significance level).

I have found the expectation and variance based on the continuous definition case.

$$
  E[X] = \dfrac{1}{θ}, \space V[X] = \dfrac{1}{θ^2}
$$

Also, I have tried to find the confidence interval based on the common case that I saw from a textbook.

$$
  \begin{align*}
     & -Φ(α) \le \dfrac{\bar{X} - 1/θ}{\sqrt{1/θ^2n}} \le Φ(α) \\
     & -\bar{X} - \dfrac{Φ(α)}{θ\sqrt{n}} \le -\dfrac{1}{θ} \le \dfrac{Φ(α)}{θ\sqrt{n}} - \bar{X} \\
     & \bar{X} + \dfrac{Φ(α)}{θ\sqrt{n}} \ge \dfrac{1}{θ} \ge \bar{X}  - \dfrac{Φ(α)}{θ\sqrt{n}} \\
     & \dfrac{θ\sqrt{n}}{θ\sqrt{n}\bar{X} +  Φ(α)} \le θ \le \dfrac{θ\sqrt{n}}{θ\sqrt{n}\bar{X}   Φ(α)}\\
  \end{align*}
$$

Yet, this quite different from what I expect to see, how can I derive the confidence interval without sampling?

Comment: You seem to want $\mathbb P(\theta \le \frac{c}{X})=1-\alpha$, i.e. $\mathbb P(X  \le \frac{c}{\theta}) =1-\alpha$.  $\mathbb P(X  \le \frac{c}{\theta}) = F(\frac c\theta)$ based on the CDF and you should find it: the $\theta$ should cancel so you can find $c$ in terms of $\alpha$

Comment: @Henry Does that mean I use the wrong approach, and what I need to do is simply find the CDF of the distribution like:
$$
    F(\dfrac{c}{θ}) = P(X \le \dfrac{c}{θ}) = \int_0^xθe^{-θx}dx
$$

and, simply compare them. I will try it again, thank you.

Comment: You need the correct limit of integration so $\int\limits_0^{c/θ} θ e^{-θx}\,dx$

Comment: I have followed your suggestion: 

$$
    \begin{align*}
        P(θ \in S(X)) & = P(θ \le \dfrac{c}{x}) = F(\dfrac{c}{x}) \\
        & = \int_0^{c/θ}θe^{-θx}dx \\
        & = 1 - e^{-c} = 1 - α \\
    \end{align*}
$$

$c = -\ln{α}$.

At first, I was thinking that I should get the confidence interval, but now, it feels like the question is roundaboutly asking for the CDF of this distribution. I guess I am not clear about those knowledge.

Comment: For a single observation $x$, using $c=-\log_e \alpha$ gives you a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\theta$ of $\left[0, \frac cx\right]$

Comment: Thanks, it becomes a bit clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the advices from Henry,

$$
  \begin{align*}
    P(θ \in S(X)) & = P(θ \le \dfrac{c}{X}) \\ & \equiv P(X \le \dfrac{c}{θ}) = F(\dfrac{c}{θ}) = \int_0^{c/θ}θe^{-θx}dx = 1 - e^{-c} = 1 - α \\
    \therefore c = -\ln{α}
  \end{align*}
$$